# How can i run two processes such that we have 'n' iterations in both processes and iterations run alternately

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, ipc

We have two processes A and B both having 'n' iterations. Lets assume ith iteration in process A is Ai and in process B is Bi. So iterations should run in the following manner:
A1 B1 A2 B2 and so on.

Now in each iteration every process takes an input and writes output to a file which acts as an input for next iteration of other process.

Comment: How long does an iteration take, approximately?

Comment: Yes, this is a essentially a problem of process synchronization and can be done using semaphores.

Comment: Well ,the time taken by the single iteration may vary so i want each process to wait until the second process completes it's iteration and updates the input file. @MarkSetchell

Comment: Is it measured in milliseconds or hours?

Comment: In milliseconds. @MarkSetchell

Comment: Sounds horrible - like it needs to be refactored into a single process with 2 threads and shared memory rather than writing disk files every few milliseconds.

Comment: Well, i want to come up with a solution to achieve the given task. 

Task: We have a 2-player game where each player has 'm' moves and after every move a input is given to another player and vice-versa. Now i have to compete two codes for the given game which will act as one of the player with each other. So i came up with this problem. If you can suggest some other way, i would be very thankful. @MarkSetchell

Comment: Can you change the code and recompile it? Are the filenames of the files the programs open fixed? To what?

Comment: Code will be compiled only once and it needs to be done at run-time. And yeah filenames are fixed. @MarkSetchell